# Use a Javascript function argument to calculate another argument of the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function ({
  arg1: ...,
  arg2: ...,
  arg3: function() {
    return (arg1 + arg2);
  }
}) { ... };
```

I wonder if something like this is possible, and if so, how do I address to the first two arguments in the third one?

PS: Below is the working code:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  scrollingSpeed: 1000,
  easingcss3: "cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1)",
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
    // this is the place where I want to use the scrollingSpeed and easingcss3 values
  },
});
```

Comment: What you posted is totally not possible. What are you trying to do exactly, I don't get it? Could you explain it on some practical code? A code that would work better if the functionality you desire existed?

Comment: you simply put the statement `arg3=arg1+arg2` in the body of the function. later you can use all 3 variables in that function. why you want to do this in this way..?

Comment: @TomášZato I've updated the code.